# Dual monitor not detected

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, display, display-manager, multiple-monitors

I've a desktop computer having Ubuntu 16.04 updated from 14.04 (It wan't working in 14.04 too though). I've two graphic cards on system. They are as follow,

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
```

I've two monitor attached on two different VGA ports, although only single monitor is detected in **System -> Display settings** and **nVidia Settings**.

Drivers for nVidia are up-to-date and working perfectly fine.

[image]

Output of **`xrandr --listproviders`**:

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x29c cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 2 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x45 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

Output of **`xrandr -q`**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any solutions? Is it Intel and nVidia don't support together on Ubuntu ? (It does work on Windows)

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr --listproviders`?

Comment: Added in my question, it shows both the providers.

Comment: and what about  `xrandr -q` ?

Comment: Added in Question.

Comment: check out the connections, are they right? cause in my setup  when I do `xrandr -q` i get  [this](http://pastebin.com/fyK1RAm8)

Comment: Yes connections are right as I see blank screen on second monitor. But nothing shows up on it.

Comment: try using the open source drivers , see if that work.

Comment: Tried, still not working. Same results.

Comment: Well I am out of ideas now.Sorry

Comment: May be I've to get HDMI to VGA converter and attach both screens from single display driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by Getting HDMI to VGA converter and using both the displays from single graphics card.
  May be Ubuntu doesn't support multiple graphics card to use with dual monitor at once, but using converter solved my issue.

Comment: nope I have worked with 3 monitors without the need of HDMI or VGA converter.

Comment: That's strange, not sure why it isn't working for me.